# In Hibernate when use ID or object in where clause?

Tags: hibernate

I am a Hibernate beginner. I am baffling about when use ID or Object in where clause (reasonable, performance, optimization).

Ex: 

`from Post p where p.category.id = :cid`

or

`from Post p where p.category = :category`

Thank for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking there is no major difference between either.  More times than not, the syntax used is often based on whatever input you have going into that HQL/JPQL.

All of these are valid:

```
// Category instance available 
List<Post> posts = session
       .createQuery( "FROM Post p WHERE p.category = :category", Post.class )
       .setParameter( "category", category )
       .getResultList();

// Category id available
List<Post> posts = session
       .createQuery( "FROM Post p WHERE p.category.id = :categoryId", Post.class )
       .setParameter( "categoryId", categoryId )
       .getResultList();

// Category instance generated by Session#load with categoryId as input
final Category category = session.load( Category.class, categoryId );
List<Post> posts = session
       .createQuery( "FROM Post p WHERE p.category = :category", Post.class )
       .setParameter( "category", category )
       .getResultList();
```

From a performance point of view, I typically prefer to use the Object-based syntax if I am being provided an already fetched entity instance, whether its detached or not.  If all I have is the identifier, I use the identifier syntax.

There is really no benefit to use the third syntax I show above other than if you rather use the Object-based syntax when your input value is solely the identifier; however, be aware that if the incoming `categoryId` does not actually represent a valid entity, `ObjectNotFoundException` will occur rather than simply receiving an empty result set because the incoming `categoryId` had no matches.